# TypeError: Session.createIndex is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I m using mongodb and mongoose for my database.
Now want I want to do is remove a collection after a specified time.
Here's what I tried:

```
const Session = mongoose.model("session", {
    key: String
})
Session.createIndex({ expireAfterSeconds: 60 * 60 * 15 } )
```

It didn't work
I just get this error:

```
TypeError: Session.createIndex is not a function
```

What can I do to fix it?
I would appreciate a example by editing my code and pasting it in answer,

Comment: Mongodb only supports removing document and index, not collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`createIndex` is a function used in MongoDb. Here, you are addressing mongoose.

I believe you wanted to use `createIndexes` function of mongoose Model class.
[Documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model)